# Simplest way to have Python output, from a compiled package?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Prior info: I'm on a Mac.

Q: How can I get terminal-like text output from the program execution, if I compile it with py2app for redistribution?

My case is a program that copies a lot of big files and takes a while to process so I would like to at least have an output notification everytime each file is copied.

This is easy if I run it on the command line, I can just print a new line.

But when I make a self-sufficient package, it simply opens on the bottom dock, with no window, and closes upon completion.

A simple text window would be fine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As I said below in response to arbarnert, in the meantime I seem to have found an interesting solution - Platypus. [link]http://sveinbjorn.org/platypus[/link] - It even gives me an easy way to create a progress bar. If I can work with it, I think that's going to be my solution! Otherwise I'll try with abarnert's suggestions.

Comment: For the most part, Platypus works in the same cases where renaming your `Foo.py` to `Foo.command` works. In particular, if you were using `py2app` because you have external dependencies, etc., Platypus won't help you with that. But if you don't really need any of the features of `py2app` besides "make an app bundle", yeah, Platypus may be exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create a simple text window, you need to pick a GUI framework to do that with. For something this simple, there's no reason not to use `Tkinter` (which comes with any Python) or `PyObjC` (which is pre-installed with Apple's Python 2.7), unless you happen to be more familiar with `wx`, `gobject`, `Qt`, etc.

At any rate, however you do it, you'll need to write a function that takes a message and appends it to the text window (maybe creating it lazily, if necessary), and call that function wherever you would normally `print`. You may also want to write and install a `logging` handler that does the same thing, so you can just `log.info` stuff. (You *could* instead create a file-like object that does this and redirect `stdout` and/or `stderr`, but unless you have no control over the `print`ing code, that's going to be a lot more work.)

The only real problem here is that a GUI needs an event loop, and you probably just wrote your code as a sequential script.

One way around that is to turn your whole current script into a background thread. If you're using a GUI library that allows you to access the widgets from background threads, everything is easy; your `printfunc` just does `textwidget.append(msg)`. If not, it may at least have a `call_on_main_thread` type function, so your `printfunc` does `call_on_main_thread(textwidget.append, msg)`. If worst comes to worst (and I believe with Tkinter, it does), you have to create an explicit queue to push messages through, and write a queue handler in the event loop. [This recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/82965-threads-tkinter-and-asynchronous-io/) should give you an idea. Replace the body of `workerThread` with your code, and end it with `self.endApplication()`. (There are probably better examples out there; this was just what I found first in a quick search.)

The other way around that is to have your code cooperatively operate with the event loop. Some libraries, like `wx`, have functions like `SafeYield` that make things work if you just call it after every chunk of processing. Others don't have that, but have a way to explicitly drive the event loop from your code. Others have neither—but every event loop framework has to have a way to schedule new events, so you can break your code up into a sequence of functions that each finish quickly and then do something like `root.after_idle(nextfunc)`.

---

However… are you sure you need to do this?

First, any app, including one created by `py2app`, will send its stdout to the terminal if you run it with `Foo.app/Contents/MacOS/Foo`. And you can even set things up so that `open Foo.app` works that way, if you want. Obviously this doesn't help for people who just double-click the app in Finder (because then there *is* no terminal), but sometimes it's sufficient to just have to output available when people need it and know how to follow instructions.

And you can take this farther: Create a `Foo.command` file that just does something like `$(dirname $0)/Foo.app/Contents/MacOS/Foo`, and when you double-click that file, it launches Terminal.app and runs your script.

Or you can get even simpler: Just use `logging` to syslog the output, and if you want to see when each file is done, just watch the log messages go by in `Console.app`.

Finally, do you even need `py2app` in the first place? If you don't have any external dependencies, just rename you script to `Foo.command`, and double-clicking it will run it in Terminal.app. If you *do* have external dependencies, you might still be able to get away with bundling it all together as a folder with a `.command` in it instead of as a `.app`.

Obviously none of these ideas are exactly a professional or newbie-friendly way to build an interface, so if that matters, you will have to create a GUI.

Comment: Thanks. In the meantime I seem to have found an interesting solution - Platypus. [link]http://sveinbjorn.org/platypus[/link] - It even gives me an easy way to create a progress bar. If I can work with it, I think that's going to be my solution! Otherwise I'll try with your suggestions.

Comment: It's not that much work, IIRC it suffices to do `sys.stdout = MyFancyObject`, with `MyFancyObject` having a `write`-method.